# Discrepancies of solutions of polynomial equation.

Tags: polynomials, roots

First of all, I have to tell you 2 things:

1. I am not sure how well I cam communicate this question
2. Secondly, I don't know under what title I should search for this particular query. So, if there is any duplicate for this question, kindly point out to me and excuse me for the trouble that has been caused

I have an equation which goes like this:
$$c_1-\frac{(x^2 - a2) a1}{x^4 - x^2 a3 - a4 (x^2 - a2)}-\frac{(x^2 - b2) b1}{x^4 - x^2 b3 - b4 (x^2 - b2)}=0$$
This can also be written as:
$$a2 b2 (a1 b4 + 
    a4 (b1 + b4 c1)) + (-b2 (a4 b1 + a1 b4 + a4 b4 c1 + 
       a3 (b1 + b4 c1)) - 
    a2 (a1 (b3 + b4) + a4 (b1 + (b3 + b4) c1))) x^2 + (a4 b1 + b1 b2 +
     a1 (a2 + b3 + b4) + a2 a4 c1 + a4 b3 c1 + a4 b4 c1 + b2 b4 c1 + 
    a3 (b1 + (b3 + b4) c1)) x^4 + (-a1 - 
    b1 - (a3 + a4 + b3 + b4) c1) x^6 + c1 x^8$$
Let's put some random values, say a1 = 2, a2 = 3, a3 = 2, a4 = 1, b1 = 4, b2 = 2, b3 = 1, b4 = 1 and c1 =  1 in both the equation. Solving both the equation for x will gives you values of x and are given as (here I stands for $\sqrt{-1}$):

-2.26346,

-1.83376,

(-1.1871 -  0.390094 I),

(-1.1871 + 0.390094 I),

(1.1871 - 0.390094 I),

(1.1871 + 0.390094 I),

1.83376 and

2.26346
(For this one can use mathematica or matlab)

Now, lets put a1=0. This in-turn means that the first equation will become equation of 4th order, with values of x being

-1.75532 + 0.284849 I

-1.75532 - 0.284849 I

1.75532 + 0.284849 I

1.75532 - 0.284849 I

But, you can see that second equation's order has not been reduced. In fact the roots that we get from second equation is:

-1.75532 - 0.284849 I

-1.75532 + 0.284849 I

-1.27123 - 0.340625 I

-1.27123 + 0.340625 I

1.27123 - 0.340625 I

1.27123 + 0.340625 I

1.75532 - 0.284849 I

1.75532 + 0.284849 I

I have got second equation from first one. So when I am putting some numerical values for the first one and solving the equation, one should get the same values for the second one too, isn't? But in this case, I am getting only 4 values from 1st equation whereas there are 8 values from second equation (in this 8 values, the 4 values corresponding to the first equation is also included).
Whys is it happening like this? Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: When getting the second equation from the first, you may be multiplying by the polynomials in the denominator, which could add the roots of those “denominator polynomials” also as extraneous solutions in the second case, whenever corresponding numerators are zero. In the first case of course the denominator cannot be zero.

Comment: Thanks @Macavity for taking time to look in this issue and it is true that "When getting the second equation from the first, you may be multiplying by the polynomials in the denominator, which could add the roots of those “denominator polynomials” also as extraneous solutions in the second ". But, how can this be resolved?

Comment: Test the solutions you get, ignore the ones which don’t work. It’s as simple as that.